# how to convert an array{Float64,1} to a Float64? in julia

Tags: julia

I just want to know how to convert an array{Float64,1} to a Float64? in julia

```
utility= rand(1)*row*c*(1-x)
```

it gives me error "array of size (1,) passed as objective; only scalar objectives are allowed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `rand()` instead of `rand(1)`. The former returns a random `Float64` value, whereas the latter returns a 1-dimensional array with one element in it. Better to keep everything as scalars in the first place if it's possible to do so.

Generally though, you can't convert a vector `v` to a scalar.  There may be more than one element in it, in which case the conversion isn't well defined.  What you can do, however, is index into the vector to extract one of its values.

Comment: actually i have to use the probability of Poisson distribution. I know how to compute just Poisson Distribution but i want to compute the probability of poission distribution. I have just lambda range from 20 to 100

Comment: @user3582228 Then you probably want to use `Distributions.jl`. But that is a separate question for you to ask.